# Tracking sender of Email via email address ONLY

Tags: email

Is there a way to track the sender and the location via the email address only.

The problem is somebody has created a similar sounding email id to send content to my official circle with a view to malign me.

It is obvious as result I am now under silent investigation and hence do not have access to the email

Answer (score 2):

*Only* the address?  Not possible.  Even with the full headers of the email it can be difficult to trace, because it's possible to forge most of them.

Comment: Technology cannot be so limiting - there has to be a way to snare this person

Comment: The address can work as a starting point for more active measures (eg. social engineering), but the address alone isn't enough.